# How to stop CORS errors with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, cors

Hi,

I have this ajax that requests data from my own domain:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var user = $("#username").val();
   var pass = $("#password").val();
     var url = '/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login&do=process';
        $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "post",
                url: url,
                data: {"auth_key" : "880ea6a14ea49e853634fbdc5015a024", "referer" : "/index.php?app=core&amp;module=global&amp;section=login&amp;do=process", "rememberMe" : "1", "username" : user, "password" : pass}, 
                success:function(data){ 
         console.log("connected");
     },
     error:function(data){ 
         console.log("there was a problem");
     } 
        });
    });
```

but I get this error on console:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login&do=process. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).`

so I added these lines to my htaccess on root

```
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
   # Always set these headers for CORS.
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,C$
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

and it still doesnt work. I wonder if I am putting it on the wrong place, maybe? My original htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I tried by adding it on top and then on bottom but nothing works. Whats the deal here?

Thank you.

Comment: That _“CORS request did not succeed”_ message indicates that the browser is failing to successfully connect to the server and initiate the request and get a response. So the CORS configuration on the server isn’t relevant to the immediate problem. That CORS configuration would probably be working as expected if the browser could actually connect to the server. In most cases when this happens, it’s due to a bad or missing SSL cert, or some other SSL failure. But it can also be due to firewall problems, or anti-virus software, or browser extensions. It’d need more debugging to isolate the cause.

Comment: You should first of all investigate, how you are even getting a CORS error to begin with - for a request to a _relative_ URL. Does the response _redirect_ to a URL with a different origin maybe? Do you have any AJAX default options set up, that could change the final URL the request is made to?